# AWS DMS Premigration Assessments Checks are not reliable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms

I'm working on merging three RDS (Postgres) via AWS DMS.

DMS suggests before launching a replication task to launch [Premigration Assessments Tasks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.AssessmentReport.html). According to AWS documentation, "a premigration assessment evaluates specified components of a database migration task to help identify any problems that might prevent a migration task from running as expected."

We had performed these tasks and we had behaviors that were not at all reassuring:

- Tests are successful while replication fails due to a connection issue to the target endpoint.
- Tests may fail, but that won't prevent the replication from going well.
- Tests can be flaky: if we run them several times in a row, we can have different errors or DMS examine the PG views and sometimes not.

Have you ever had similar experiences with these premigration assessment checks?

Comment: Yes, this happens sometimes. Have you checked the logs for each task run? This will be helpfull when looking for problems. You could also check the task settings to understand some of the "decisions" DMS makes when replicating databases. I suggest you start here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TaskSettings.FullLoad.html